# Why is Xcode always causing issues for Flutter apps?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

Serious question. Has anyone ever had a good experience? Any tips on how to not spend days and days getting over Xcode issues?

I've never had a good time setting up a Flutter app to run on Android studio. It's always an Xcode issue.

Comment: It's almost never an issue from flutter unless it's not done properly. Being a unity developer it was super hard to export an xcode project then to build an ipa. From flutter it's super easy .

Comment: @KaushikChandru Would you mind sharing your process, since you never run into issues? That's what my question is.

Comment: Depends on the project. Things I keep in mind while development is  While I add a package in pub spec I make sure I add all required permissions and data in info.plist, check the documentation for any iOS specific steps to do. If I have problems with Pods, I delete Pods, clean all folder and rebuild. I don't do anything more other than this.